# Does everything that happens to me happens because of me?

Tags: karma

I always wonder that my self. People scam me because I am not wise.

What happened?

Is there always something I did that causes that? How do I know that?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even though it's not a bad question, it's way too open for interpretation, even within the scope of buddhism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surrounded by deceit and scams, probably the most important thing to consider first is our own conduct:

> [MN8:12.32](https://suttacentral.net/mn8/en/sujato#mn8:12.32): ‘Others will be deceitful, but here we will not be deceitful.’

With right view about our conduct we can then seek out others with equal views about conduct. In this way our choices lead us upwards, away from deceit, away from scams, away from people who would tempt us with scams.

> [SN45.3:1.3](https://suttacentral.net/sn45.3/en/sujato#sn45.3:1.3): “Sir, good friends, companions, and associates are the whole of the spiritual life.”

To lead a life without regret and remorse, embrace ethics and become a good friend who rejoices in other good friends. With Right View, step onto the Noble Eightfold Path practicing ethics, wisdom and immersion.

Answer (score 0):

People scam others because of greed, hatred & delusion in their mind.

That we get scammed is because most of us do not have perfect knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

There are these relevant Sutta;

> https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn36/sn36.021.than.html
>   "Master Gotama, there are some brahmans & contemplatives who are of this doctrine, this view: Whatever an individual feels — pleasure, pain, neither-pleasure-nor-pain — is entirely caused by what was done before. Now what does Master Gotama say to that?"
>
> [The Buddha:] "There are cases where some feelings arise based on bile.[1] You yourself should know how some feelings arise based on bile. Even the world is agreed on how some feelings arise based on bile. So any brahmans & contemplatives who are of the doctrine & view that whatever an individual feels — pleasure, pain, neither-pleasure-nor-pain — is entirely caused by what was done before — slip past what they themselves know, slip past what is agreed on by the world. Therefore I say that those brahmans & contemplatives are wrong."
>
> "There are cases where some feelings arise based on phlegm... based on internal winds... based on a combination of bodily humors... from the change of the seasons... from uneven[2] care of the body... from harsh treatment... from the result of kamma. You yourself should know how some feelings arise from the result of kamma. Even the world is agreed on how some feelings arise from the result of kamma. So any brahmans & contemplatives who are of the doctrine & view that whatever an individual feels — pleasure, pain, neither pleasure-nor-pain — is entirely caused by what was done before — slip past what they themselves know, slip past what is agreed on by the world. Therefore I say that those brahmans & contemplatives are wrong."

There is also this Sutta, it's too long to post all the relevant excerpts tho http://dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN101.html